# How to authenticate devices across organisation boundaries without a third party CA

Tags: security, authentication

I'm currently working on a protocol which passes automated instructions between separate organisations.  I'm looking for a way to delegate authentication of devices to which ever organisation a device belongs to.  This doesn't affect authorisation models, only authentication.

So to put this in terms of DNS domains:

- organisation `foomy.tld` should be able to authenticate (eg: sign the certificate for?) `new_deive.foomy.tld`.
- organisation `acme.tld` could choose to trust `foomy.tld`:

  - It should then be able to trust `new_device.foomy.tld` is what it says it is on the authority of `foomy.tld`
  - BUT organisation `acme.tld` should NEVER trust `foomy.tld` to authenticate any device outside the domain of `foomy.tld`.

#### Considering using x509 and SSL

In the case of x509 CA certificates, the CA role is usually performed by a third party CA.  But that isn't appropriate for this purpose:

- The creation / destruction of device IDs (services) is too rapid to consider a traditional CA (too expensive, too slow).
- This mechanism needs to authenticate clients and servers.  Devices / services do not always have public IP addresses so CA solutions such as LetsEncrypt aren't an option.
- Creating a dedicated CA for this single purpose is not cost effective and likely to damage adoption.

So this leads to the idea of an organisation acting as their own CA for this purpose.  But as it turns out, x509 really doesn't support this well, because once you accept a CA as being trustworthy you cannot limit the scope of that trust enough.  IE: [You cannot trust it to only sign certificates for it's own domain](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/31376/can-i-restrict-a-certification-authority-to-signing-certain-domains-only).

#### Considering re-purposing single sign on mechanisms

The single sign-on mechanisms I've looked at appear to be built around the concept of authenticating users.  Background automated services don't appear to be well supported.

Maybe I missed something here.

#### Question - Keeping it as narrow as possible.

Is there another approach allowing this type of cross organisation authentication which I can use for my problem ?

Comment: This is exactly the kind of question where I think parts of the community act too strict in interpreting the site scope - yes, the last sentence is *literally* a request for 3rd party resources, which is off-topic here, so it already got two downvotes by some site cops for this reason (and an anonymous downvote). But this can be easily fixed by a small edit (which I did now), so why downvote in the first place instead of telling the OP what they should change?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. The changed wording is fine with me.

Comment: You can obviously do this *if you control the code which does the validation*.  Since you say you are "working on a protocol" it would seem that is a possibility - it's not like this needs to work in every random web browser.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes, you are right that obscure SSL libraries don't need to be supported.  I would however expect it to be simple enough to re-implement.  That makes it dangerous to rely on a feature only available with one obscure library.

Comment: It's not a feature "only available with one obscure library" - if you control the code, you can only pass it the cert appropriate for the domain you are using it against in that call.  Pass a different cert when you use it against another domain.

Comment: @ChrisStratton perhaps I misunderstood you are you suggesting I write my own SSL validation library?

Comment: No.  What I'm saying is that when you make calls to whatever SSL library you are using which open connections to a particular host, pass it only the certificate applicable to that specific host's domain.  You will of course need to do this on a connection basis, ie, below the level of any application protocol engine which might handle something like an HTTP redirect.

Comment: *The creation / destruction of device IDs (services) is too rapid to consider a traditional CA (too expensive, too slow).* A root CA can issue an intermediate certificate for your organization. You can then issue certificates yourself, as rapidly as you want,.

Comment: @JohnWu How would that intermediate certificate be limited?

Comment: @PhilipCouling I am not sure what you mean. Nobody can use that intermediate certificate to generate other certificates unless they have its private key, which your organization would control. So you can limit the certificate in any way you want.

Comment: @JohnWu The core of my question is achieving *limited* trust.  As discussed here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/31376/can-i-restrict-a-certification-authority-to-signing-certain-domains-only and here https://serverfault.com/questions/605643/getting-an-intermediate-ssl-certificate

Comment: Can you explain why it is a problem if you get a certificate from a different domain signed by `foomy.tld`?  As you note this is not authorization.  In other words, even if you were using a third-party CA, you wouldn't just accept any request that came with a certificate signed by a 3rd-party CA.

Comment: @JimmyJames what you've just asked there is *why is it a problem to allowin `foomy.tld` to impersonate whoever they like from any organisation?*  Is the answer to that not clear?

Comment: @PhilipCouling Not exactly.  What that would mean is that (assuming they haven't lost control of their keys) foomy.tld is vouching that the certificate is from that organization.  But that doesn't mean you need to accept the request.  In other words, you can deal with this as an authorization step.  Trusting the CA doesn't mean that you must trust every entity with a certificate from that CA.

Comment: @JimmyJames Okay what you are suggesting there is apply an additional layer of authentication code which interrogates the certificate chain.  You're effectivly suggesting I maually implement `nameconstraints`  Authorisation is an entirely separate subject and really shouldn't be dragged into this.

Comment: If by 'manually' you mean write an if statement that checks that the CA domain is the same as the domain of the subject of the certificate, yes.  Unless you use some sort of code generation tooling, I guess.  It makes sense for what you want to do to be a thing but I guess you have to figure out how much time and effort you want to put into avoiding writing a tiny bit of code.

Comment: The simplicity of this wholly depends on the languages and libraries used.  Traversing certificate hierarchies in some languages is simple, in others it's a bit of a pig.  But I take your point.

Comment: @PhilipCouling Whether you use NameConstraints or not, it's still up to some code, somewhere, to check that constraint is met.  If you can't find a library that supports this, I think you are back to doing the check.  I'm not clear on how that option helps you though.  Unless you are issuing the certificate to the entity, how would you enforce that the constraint be set?  I'm not really sure what you mean be 'working on a protocol' here.  Are you building an implementation or writing a spec?

Comment: @PhilipCouling Not arguing.  I'm just trying to be helpful.  I apologize for being bothersome.  I looked at the question again and thought perhaps I misunderstood the problem.

Comment: I think you missed a point not stated (I hadn't thought it relevant).  The protocol is HTTP (REST).  Authorisation is only required on the server, but authentication is required on both server and client.  AFAIK getting the certificate from a HTTP REST client library after it connects yet before it sends any data is going to be tricky at best.  Yet it would not be required if the SSL library implemented the constraint.

Comment: @PhilipCouling Sorry, I didn't see this until now (you didn't @ me.)  Are you using 2-way TLS i.e. using client-certs?  If you are, that all happens during the [handshake](https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-tls-client-auth/).

Answer (score 2):

X509 certificates may contain namecontraints (see https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO4583.html for a brief summary of the fields).  You might be able to use these.

Openssl documents these nameconstraints as well https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man5/x509v3_config.html, so it can probably handle them in certificates.

I found this blog by Vadims Podāns: https://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/x509-name-constraints-certificate-extension-all-you-should-know.aspx
It claims that both Windows cryptoAPI and OpenSSL support name constrains.  It gives a sample of how to configure Microsft certreq.exe.  And it describes some scenarios where this may be useful.

On security.stackexchange there is a question about whether MacOS supports them: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/95600/are-x-509-nameconstraints-on-certificates-supported-on-os-x
And MacOS does not support name constraints.

[Thomas Pornin](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/655/thomas-pornin) on security.stackexchange [describes](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/31382/66532) why name constraints do not work in SSL.  Your situation is not SSL tough, you might be able to enforce checking the name constraint not not falling back to the common name.

I haven't tried nameconstraints though.

Comment: Interesting point. Name constraints are exactly the feature that were discouraged in the link I gave due to lack of support. Admittedly that link was from 2013. Support by openssl is useful but openssl is by no means ubiquitous.